# How to know if a Spring MDP Listener is Alive?

Tags: spring, listener, heartbeat, mdp

I have a Spring MDP listener deployed as a war that listens to a JMS queue and replies back for synchronous request-reply messages. What is the best way to monitor if the listener is alive ? Or think it more of how to set up a monitor for a web app to check if it is up and running in a java app server?

Answer (score 0):

Send a message to it and see if you get a (proper) reply.